# Taxonomy link not working (leads to 404 page)

Tags: taxonomy, links, 404-error

I've created a website where I use Taxonomies for adding an extra category future. This feature works in the backend (admin) and is showing up correctly under the article. The problem is that the link doesn't work. If I click on the Taxonomy-link, it sends me to a 404 page.

This is the article: http://7ef.8b5.myftpupload.com/test/

You must click on 'Videoblogs' next to 'Soort blog' to see the problem. So what I want is to have an archive/collection page of all the posts what have the same taxonomy when you click on the taxonomy.

This is the code I added in the functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_soortpost_taxonomy' );

function create_soortpost_taxonomy() {
register_taxonomy(
    'soortpost',
    'post',
    array(
        'label' => 'Soort Post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    )
);
}
```

And the code for showing the output of the Taxonomy link in single.php is:

```
<?php
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->link , 'soortpost' );
                    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                    // Loop over each item since it's an array
                     if ( $terms != null ){
                     foreach( $terms as $term ) {

                     // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT

             echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'soortpost').'">'.$term->name.'</a>'; 

 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
unset($term);
      } } ?>
```

Comment: If you came on this page from search, maybe that answer for similar question (but with custom `post_type` and custom `taxonomy`) will be useful: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223216/have-posts-return-false-but-count-says-3/281694#281694

Comment: Did you flush permalinks after adding the taxonomy?

Comment: a) just re-save settings>permalinks b) check whether you do have **same or similar slugs** with post types, if you do, you must **register the taxonomies first** and then the post types (e.g. `/mylife` for post type and `/mylife/regions` for taxonomy) (my suspicion is that the "subset" in slug rewrites needs to be added later, therefore this order)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you do not have a `template` for your custom `taxonomy`.
I do not think so `single.php` will be used for this purpose. 
Have a look on this [ARTICLE](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/).. Look at the hierarchy,,,

I think in your case you need `taxonomy-soortpost.php`

Taxonomy hierarchy:

- taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
- taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
- tag-{slug}.php
- tag-{id}.php
- category-{slug}.php
- category-{ID}.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try. But it says when it's looking for page or archive.php, and will not find it, then it uses the index.php. But what I don't get is that a categorie page uses a same lay-out, as well for the search results. What I'm trying to say is that it's strange it can't generate a taxonomy page by itself?