# have_posts() return false but count says "3"

Tags: loop, taxonomy, terms

The situation is this: I have created a custom post type which works perfectly, now I want to create a specific archive page template for the taxonomies of this post type.

I duplicated the `archive.php` page of my theme (schema by MTS) but it doesn't work in this case.

Here the code:

```
<?php

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ), get_query_var( 'count' ) );
echo $term->name;
echo ' has nr elements: ';
echo $term->count;


?>
<div id="page">
    <div class="<?php mts_article_class(); ?>">
        <div id="content_box">
            <h1 class="postsby">
                <span><?php echo the_archive_title(); ?></span>
            </h1>
            <?php $j = 0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <article class="latestPost excerpt  <?php echo (++$j % 3 == 0) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
                    <?php mts_archive_post(); ?>
                </article><!--.post excerpt-->
                <?php endwhile; else: echo 'nothing'; endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $j !== 0 ) { // No pagination if there is no posts ?>
                <?php mts_pagination(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The strange aspect is that the code print "nothing" because the function `have_posts()` return false but the `$term->count` is `3`.

Can you help me please? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what is your 4th parameter on [`get_term_by`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) ?

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $wp_query );` and inspect the main query object

Comment: @Jevuska I used 'count' to get the number of element with that slug, is it wrong used in this way?
@ Pieter I answered you below :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

According to [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/):

```
The hierarchy for a custom taxonomy is listed below:

taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
taxonomy.php
archive.php
index.php
```

So, it doesn't matter witch template file you are using, all of them will generate same issue.

When I put in the beginning of template file code `var_dump($wp_query);`, i found this:

```
public 'request' => string 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (20)
) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10' (length=433)
  public 'posts' =>
```

Important part in this query is `wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment')`.

Problem occur because there is no your custom `post_type` in this array `('post', 'page', 'attachment')`.

I don't know why it's happen, but it's possible to fix it using `pre_get_posts` hook:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query');
function add_custom_post_type_to_query($query) {
    // We do not want unintended consequences.
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;    
    }

    // Check if custom taxonomy is being viewed
    if( is_tax() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) )         
    {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 
            'post',
            'page',
            'my_custom_post_type'
        ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue as the OP.  As @sviriden noted in his answer, the problem is that the main query is not including your custom post type in the `wp_posts.post_type IN` clause.  I tracked down the issue in `class-wp-query.php` to these lines:

```
    if ( 'any' == $post_type ) {
        $in_search_post_types = get_post_types( array( 'exclude_from_search' => false ) );
        if ( empty( $in_search_post_types ) ) {
            $where .= ' AND 1=0 ';
        } else {
            $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ('" . join( "', '", array_map( 'esc_sql', $in_search_post_types ) ) . "')";
        }
    } elseif ( ! empty( $post_type ) && is_array( $post_type ) ) {
        $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ('" . join( "', '", esc_sql( $post_type ) ) . "')";
    } elseif ( ! empty( $post_type ) ) {
        $where           .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = %s", $post_type );
        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
    } elseif ( $this->is_attachment ) {
        $where           .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'attachment'";
        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'attachment' );
    } elseif ( $this->is_page ) {
        $where           .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'page'";
        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'page' );
    } else {
        $where           .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'post'";
        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );
    }
```

The key is the `$in_search_post_types` which only includes Custom Post Types that have `exclude_from_search` as false.  In my case I had `exclude_from_search` as `true` when registering the custom post type.  Changing this value to `false` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong here is your assumptions that the values should be the same. I don't know of the top of my head what exactly the term count represent, and it is not apparent from the docs, but it is most likely a raw number of posts associated with the term. OTOH `wp_query` (which is used for the main loop) takes into account user permissions on top of that raw number, simplest example - by default the result will not include posts which are not published, more complex things can happen if you have some plugins which manipulate the query.